# How to use terminal keyboard shortcuts inside emacs multi-term

Tags: emacs

I know there's some questions that are kind of related to this already, and I know you can do stuff like

```
(defun term-send-esc ()
  "Send ESC in term mode."
  (interactive)
  (term-send-raw-string "\e"))
```

but it would be very convenient if there was kind of a univerisal override keybinding. For example, I just ssh:ed into a remote server and tried to nano a file and couldn't figure out how to exit because Ctl-x listens for emacs bindings. Is there such a thing?

Comment: `(define-key term-raw-map [?\C-x] 'term-send-raw)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two term sub modes, `term-char-mode` (`C-x C-k`) and `term-line-mode` (`C-x C-j`).  Char mode is closer to a terminal, line mode is closer to a regular buffer.  IIRC, multiterm starts in char mode, but it rebinds some keys to make it more Emacs-like.  Look at the keys that multiterm rebinds; it has some alists that are used to modify the existing term-mode keymaps instead of using its own keymap.  Or use sane-term, which is not much more than some commands to create new term buffers (no mucking with key bindings).

Answer (score 1):

> Ctl-x listens for emacs bindings.

Not in the default `term-char-mode` it doesn't, so your problem is most likely with your own config.

Run a terminal in `emacs -Q` to confirm the standard behaviour.